# Displaying UserControls on menu command action

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I want to show Windows/UserControls inside my main window.
When I click a menu item, I want to show these in different windows.

I use MVVM light and postsharp with WPF.

When I click a menu item, the command gets into the relaycommand method (`GetCustomerView`) and creates a new `Object`, but is not displaying the `Window`. But when I create it inside the constructor, the `Window` displays without any problem.
What could I have messed up?
What to do to repair it?
I'm new to MVVM. Thanks in advance.

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(GetCustomerView);
        //CurrentView = new CreateCustomerViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CustomerCommand { get; set; }

    private void GetCustomerView()
    {
        CurrentView = new CreateCustomerViewModel();
    }
}   // probably the ending '}' of the class --- added by editor!
```

Edit: It looked like this from beginning but I entered the code wrong.
If I uncomment the code //CurrentView it shows the View on Application Start, not on Menu Item command Execution

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code you have supplied, you haven't implemented a constructor as you state, although every class is given a null constructor by default.  The end of your class definition is right after you define your `CustomerCommand`.  I think you want to remove the curly brace after `CustomerCommand`.  Also, I think what you intended was the following:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(GetCustomerView);
        //CurrentView = new CreateCustomerViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand CustomerCommand { get; set; }

    private void GetCustomerView()
    {
        CurrentView = new CreateCustomerViewModel();
    }
}   // probably the ending '}' of the class --- added by editor!
```